# Share files via bluetooth to another device with the same app android

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, share, device

i have one doubt about share files via bluetooth. The question is...i installed the same app in 2 devices...and i want to know if there is a way to share files (setlist as example) between them...and saved it on an internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

which app have you installed (on which phone) ? Does the app which you have installed have the feature of sharing files via bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,as @Mount said the app you installed must have the feature of sharing files via bluetooth. If you are looking for such an app, you can use Bluetooth file manager or something. There are many such apps available on the Play Store.

Comment: Hi Mount and Akash...what i need is to know if my app will recognize itself in another device when i want to share a Setlist (just a .txt with the values of my database table) via bluetooth...and when it start to transfer if there is a possibility to put the file in the app internal storage.